# Prove that the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Prove that the function defined by $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$.
Hint: Consider for example $x = 1/2nπ$ and $y = 1/[(2n+1/2)π]$

I have an answer with let $ε = 1/2$
we must have $|f(x)-f(y)|< ε =1/2$

$f(x)= \sin(1/x)=\sin(2nπ)$
and $f(y)= \sin(1/y)= \sin(2nπ+π/2)$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sin(2nπ)-\sin(2nπ+π/2)|=|0-1|=1 > 1/2=ε$
so $f(x)$ by contradiction is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

is this going in the right direction. Im really unsure if i have missed an important part! thanks for your help!

Adding this:
so i have $|x-y|<δ$ let $δ>0, |x-y|=|1/2nπ - 1/(2n+1/2)π|=|[π/2]/[2nπ(2nπ+π/2)| < δ$ so we have that when $n$ tends to infinity $|x-y|$ tends to $0$

is this complete then? Sorry for the confusing symbols!

Comment: Yeah, you basically have it. The point is, once you have chosen $\epsilon = 1/2$, choose *any* $\delta$. By choosing $n$ large enough, the corresponding $x$ and $y$ you describe will be within $\delta$ of each other, but the $\epsilon$ estimate fails.

Comment: I assume you are using the sequential criterion to prove non-uniform continuity. If so, you are almost there. You need to show that $\lim_{n} (x_n-y_n) = 0$.

Comment: As $x$ changes from an infinitely small nonzero "number" to another infinitely small nonzero "number", $\sin(1/x)$ goes all the way from $1$ to $-1$.  Uniform continuity requires infinitely small changes in the argument to result in infinitely small changes in the value.  Mere continuity, on the other hand, requires that to happen only when changing from a real number in the domain to a number infinitely close to it.

Comment: Similarly $e^x$ changes by only an infinitely small amount for infinitely small changes in $x$ if $x$ is real, but if $x$ is infinitely large, then $e^x$ can increase by $1$ when $x$ increases by a mere infinitesimal, so $x\mapsto e^x$ is _not_ uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Michael since we're not doing nonstandard analysis, there's no such thing as a nonzero infinitely small number. Even there the function's change between two points infinitely close together would be infinitely small. We need to use finitely small numbers here.

Comment: @NattS : That is precisely why I restricted this to comments rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: All you need to finish is to say that,  given any  d>0, there is an n large enough that |x-y|<d, but |f(x)-f(y)|>1/2.

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track.  You just need to write it in such a way that the reader can be sure that there's only one thing you could mean.  The point is that there is no $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y$ at distance $<\delta$ from each other you have $|f(x)-f(y)|<1/2$.  That's the same as saying that for every $\delta>0$ there exist $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge1/2$.  Your way of finding $x$ and $y$ is correct.